# Angular 2 4 HttpClient. POST request - how to get status code

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

How can I get status code of response POST request?
My service method return:

```
return this.httpClient.post(url, body, {observe: 'response'})
            .catch(HandleError.handleErrorClient);
```

In my component I call this method and subscribe:

```
    .subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
            this.responseStatus = res.status;
            console.log(this.responseStatus);
        },
        err => {
            this.responseStatus = err.status;
        });
```

But in browser console there is nothing - but when the request contains a error then `this.responseStatus = err.status` return correct status code, but `res.status` or `res` doesn't contain status code, only response body.

**EDIT:**

Component:

```
responseStatus: number;

loginUser() {
    this.loginData = this.loginForm.getRawValue();
    this.userLoginService.loginUser(this.loginData)
        .subscribe(
            res => {
                console.log('bla bla');
                this.responseStatus = res.status;
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err.status); //401
                console.log(err.error.error); //undefined
                console.log(JSON.parse(err.error).error); //unauthorized
                this.responseStatus = err.status;
            });
}
```

Service:

```
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

...

    constructor(private http: Http, private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    }


    loginUser(loginData: LoginForm) {
        return this.httpClient.post(this.loginURL, loginData, {observe: 'response'})
            .catch(HandleError.handleError);
    }
```

handle-error.ts

```
export class HandleError {

    static handleError(error: Response | any) {
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(error);
    }
}
```

POST: /api/login
[image]
I'm login correctly, but nothing more... I expected in browser console: `console.log('bla bla');`. With `Http` there isn't problems.

Comment: Have you tried to console.log resp.headers ?

Comment: By any chance, is your log level output set to "all levels" ? If not, you might only see errors (which you do)

Comment: @VivekDoshi, `console.log(res.headers)` not help. @Tim, I don't know what you mean. I use of Firefox and in my browser console I have all options set (network, css, js, security, server).
But I see also, that even `.subscribe(res => console.log('blah blah blah'))` not print... but when I use normal `Http` (not `HttpClient`), it all works.

Comment: Does the request get sent at all (using HttpClient) ?

Comment: @Tim, Yes, the request is sent. I'm doing this on the login example, I'm sending a POST request (pass, OK status) and it does not return any data (it looks like that's not even enter there `res => ...`). I will update my post with some cods for a moment.

Comment: @Tim I updated my post. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try without mixing the two http versions. Remove the http and keep httpclient. Also, only keep import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; in your app.module.ts

Comment: Result is the same. I don't know why, so I just need to keep using `Http`.

Comment: Anybody got answer for this?